# Can Magic Mouth sing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can [magic mouth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-mouth) convey as a message a song (or at least something that resembles one)?

Its description states "...and **recites** the message in **your voice** and at the **same volume** you spoke".

A message that could be written as "nà, nananà, nà, nà, nà" could be "spoken" using appropriate volumes and tones for the individual words — that would be a melody. I mean, speech is a more complex thing than just "volume", since there is also the voice tone that varies frequencies.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> [A] magical mouth appears on the object and recites the message in your voice and at the same volume you spoke. If the object you chose has a mouth or something that looks like a mouth (for example, the mouth of a statue), the magical mouth appears there so that the words appear to come from the object’s mouth. When you cast this spell, you can have the spell end after it delivers its message, or it can remain and repeat its message whenever the trigger occurs.

So, if the caster sings the original message (25 words or less, over 10 minutes or less) then the spell will sing the message when it activates. Because the spell explicitly reproduces the message **as the caster spoke it**. If that message was delivered by Beyonce to "all the single ladies" then that's what the recipient would hear.

Answer (score -1):

The weird thing about magic mouth is the timing. I would have thought it was basically a recording of your voice, but it takes only one minute to cast. (This is in 5e; not sure which edition your referencing here.) Therefore, it can't be a straight up recording because it can be delivered over the course of up to 10 minutes, but nowhere does it say that changes the one minute casting time. So if it isn't a direct recording, that might bring into question whether it can sing. Personally, I allow it to sing, because it's just too cool to not allow it.

Comment: Try to answer the actual question. Your observation is not wrong, but the difference in timing does not seem to help to solve the question. Mabybe provide clear reasoning as to why it would.